# Facing problem in implementing OnClickListener on android

Tags: android, button, buttonclick

I want to implement a click listener for a button on my main view. My code is something like below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    ...
    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(mFinishListener);
    ...
}

private OnClickListener mFinishListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};
```

But shows me error as follows

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (DialogInterface.OnClickListener)  MobileTrackerActivity.java  /MobileTracker/src/com/example/mobiletracker    line 37 Java Problem
```

I have no idea what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct interface to instantiate the `mFinishLinstener` variable...

It is possible you have an import specifying `DialogInterface` and that is confusing the view.

Try specifying `View.OnClickListener` explicitly.

```
private View.OnClickListener mFinishListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my opinion Best way to implement On click event for the Button.

Instead of applying an OnClickListener to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the android:onClick attribute. For example:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the activity's selfDestruct(View) method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. For example:

```
public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Kabloey
 }
```

Note: The above code is given in [Android SDK - Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this code :::

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this one as:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
@Override   
 public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like below code..

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
   //Write Your code here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the onclick in the xml.

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onclick="buttonClick" />
```

And in your code you would define the function as:

```
public void buttonClick(View view)
{
    // handle click
}
```